# How to tell GWT development mode to include files from a module configured as dependency?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, module, http-status-code-404

I am trying to create a combined GWT application from two existing GWT applications which used to run separately in parallel. The existing applications were module "A" and "B" in the IntelliJ project, resulting in two artifacts a.war and b.war.
I thought the best approach would be to add an additional module "All" that includes both modules as dependencies and will result in a single artifact "all.war".

The problem I have now is that some files (css and third party javascript) that are used by module A and referenced from the host page are not found from development mode: I get 404 status messages for the browser requests for for these files. They are, however, contained in the generated artifact/war file.
In the project settings for module A, they are contained in the directory configured as the web resource directory of module A's web facet. I am not able to configure this directory as web resource directory of module "All" as the IntelliJ UI does not allow me to use any directory outside of module "All"s root directory there. As these files are not needed by module B, I would have hoped I could leave the structure modular, and not move these files to somewhere in module All's directory structure.

As I am using an old version of GWT, this is the classic plugin based development mode, not super dev mode.

Is there any way how I can tell development mode to use these files from a module configured as dependency?

Comment: Is it an option for you, to use those files via a `ClientBundle`? This could work in your scenario.
P.S. I find it difficult to believe there's no option to tell IntelliJ to pick up additional files from a given location. Disclaimer: I haven't worked with IntelliJ in years, so it's easy to be wrong. In Eclipse, the workaround is to create some sort of shortcut in the project, which points to your external files. Then you include the shortcut as static folder.

Comment: Are you using 2 modules on purpose, GWT works better (althouth compiles slower) when the whole app is compiled at once. Anyway if in each gwt-app module you only uses the GWT public folders to add static resources, a multimodule devmode should pick it up correctly (means, don't use webapp folder in gwt-app modules). And finally, compose all modules using overlays. This is just a poor explanation of the tbroyer archetype (https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes).

Comment: @IgnacioBaca The purpose of combining both modules is not the common resources, but as a common toplevel navigation is required that opens a page from module A or one from B, depending on the selected navigation entry. And the user should also easily be able to open a page from module A when currently working in a page from module B and vice versa.

Comment: @Andrei Do you know how the ClientBundle can be told to copy its contents to a directory if I do not actually reference it directly from my code? The external Javascript file is a charting library which is called from two `native`(in the sense of GWT) methods.

Comment: Need more info. Are you using maven? Also, the term "modules" is pretty confusing as there are maven modules, gwt.xml modules, and gwt compilation modules (which are gwt.xml but is the final step). Also, the final gwt compilation module frequently is bundled in a war which can even be bundled again in another war (called this composition war overlays). So reformulating your question to reduce this confusion might help, maybe even you solve the problem yourself if you correctly define which modules you are using and how.

Comment: TIP: you should use a one-to-one maven-module gwt-compilation-module bc of limitations of maven (so this restriction reduce a lot your options, easier to choose!). So if you have right now a project with this maven modules module-a-war (gwt-app), module-b-war (gwt-app), you can create 2 more modules module-common (gwt-lib) and module-ab-war (gwt-app) moving most of the gwt source code to module-common.

Comment: @IgnacioBaca No Maven involved, pure IntelliJ. Andif I talk about "modules", I am talking about IntelliJ "modules" in the IntelliJ "prject Structure" dialog.